# Archive article after a certain ttl specified nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i have two collections.

1. active_posts collection
2. archived_posts collection

I would like to know if there is a npm module or a mongo feature that will let an active post move to the archived collection when it lived (or was published) for say 20 days.

My post schema is this (temporary):

```
var postSchema = new Schema({
  title: {type:String},
  created_time: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  archived: {type: Boolean, default:false}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

***There is no time triggers in MongoDB to do this action by default***.

Here are a few workarounds:

### 1. Background Service Archiving

You can use a scheduler to run repeatedly (let's say every 5 minutes) and checks for documents in the *active_posts* collection which have passed their TTL, then transfers them to your *archived_posts* collection.

Read the following Stack Overflow post to find some scheduling libraries for Node.js:
[Is there a job scheduler library for node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785736/is-there-a-job-scheduler-library-for-node-js)

Here are some libraries to name a few: [node-cron](http://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron), [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule), [Agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda), ...

### 2. Scheduled (Delayed) Archiving

You can schedule the archiving job for each document at the time of creation.

In addition to libraries mentioned above, you can use [Kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) which has an option for scheduling a job to be done once in a certain time.

---

**TIP**:
MongoDB has a built-In functionality to delete documents after they pass their TTL, you may find it useful in conjunction with these methods. ***But use with caution!***
You can read about it in the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data), and in the following Stack Overflow post:
[Delete MongoDB document at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472125/delete-mongodb-document-at-specific-time)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, i found some modules like ol-mongoose-ttl that does what i want, but it works on the whole document, just like the built-in feature of MongoDB. What i want is to work on single entries or rows in a document. I can't seem to find any. A scheduler seems a bit complicated to me.

Comment: @NaoufalELBANTLI If you find anything that suits your requirements, consider posting it as an answer here for future reference.