# How to delete a particular document automatically in mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

*I want to delete a particular task document automatically. createdAt: {type: Date} => it will take future date and time, and duration:{type: String} => it will take time in hours. whenever the future time arrives from that time to next how much duration we insert, after completion of duration the task document will delete*

````
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    taskName: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String },
    creator: { type: String },
    duration: { type: String },
    createdAt: {type: Date}
})

const Tasks = mongoose.model('Task', TaskSchema)

module.exports = Tasks```


**Please help how to approach this task**
````

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  const TestSchema = new Schema({
        expire_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now, expires: "your desired value"} 
    })
```

this is the solution you are looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652107/13126651)

Comment: once a data is created with a duration, it should be automatically deleted after the assigned duration. That means if I create a task called "Interview Assignment" with duration set to 30 mins at 1:00pm on 1 January, the record in the database will be automatically removed at 1:30pm on 1st January.