# Auto delete a document after specific time in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema, ttl

I want to delete a document after a specified amount of time. Like if the user selects 24 hours then it should be auto-deleted after 24 hours. I heard about TTL in mongo but in that, I have to specify a time in the schema and it will be the same for all documents.

Is there any way to dynamically set the expiration time for every document?

Comment: Have you checked out the [TTL index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/)?

Comment: I have checked but it doesn't have the option of dynamic expiration time setting. we have to set expiration time in schema only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete MongoDB document at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38472125/delete-mongodb-document-at-specific-time)

Comment: Yes, I have already found out the solution on internet and posted the same for others as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add a field like expireAt and it will contain the Date of expiration. Now add a TTL index like this-

```
db.dbname.createIndex({expireAt:1},{expireAfterSeconds:0})
```

Now just add expireAt field in every document with the expiration Date. It will auto-remove when the current time reaches the expiration date.

Answer (score -1):

There is no system to support this per se, one suggestion is that you add a Date attribute to each document you want to delete and maintain a job that checks documents that have this attribute/if the attribute value has passed the current time, if so, delete the document.